# Which is the best suitable back-end framework for Android Applications?

Tags: android, json, backend, php

I am developing android application, and I want to implement PHP as backend. I like to ask about which PHP framework is suitable for developing with Android application. My android Application will use JSON. Also, application uses authentication, data services in backend.

So, I need to know which framework is mostly suitable for this purpose??
Advance thanks for everyone!!

Comment: Android have no any dependency with the framework. You only need a simple script to communicate with the Android. Now its up to you using which framework you can minimize your back-end effort.

Comment: @Dharmendra : I know there is no dependency between Android and Php framework. I am asking which PHP framework is most suitable for handling backend operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) or [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/). Using those frameworks, you should concept and implement an API, preferably [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), which provides your Android application with data and can be used later on for all other kind of mobile apps or third party applications.

If you go with [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/) you can have a look for the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) - a bundle which provides tools to create a RESTful API.

Comment: Thanx for suggestions. I preferably go for Symfony 2.

Comment: I'm using Kohana 3.1 which has has a built in controller to handle restful requests nicely.  It appears to not be included in Kohana 3.2 but you easily port it.